# Enhance performance in simulation of data frames

Tags: r, performance, simulation, resampling

When coding I often just code how it comes up in my mind. Though I think I have learned efficient R coding from the beginning (e. g. avoiding `for` ...  `if` loops) my solutions are not always really driven by performance. Unfortunately sometimes it can get crucial to know what is the most efficient code - and I want to learn that!

Currently I am simulating a number of data frames combined into a list. After the simulation I need a second data frame with mean and SD of all columns throughout the list. *('Simulation' here means that some variables are being simulated/resampled from an other data frame, other variables are just random normal or binominal distributed values with specific b_0. For the sake of brevity I spared out the first part with the resampling here.)*

My code (see the example below) produces perfectly the expected outcome, but it seems to be first, a bit slow (I'm talking about hours in the real thing), and second, highly RAM consuming (for that I temporary reduced the amount of simulated dfs in the list).

For the simulation I know defining a data.frame within the function could be an issue, but I don't know how to do it better. For the mean/SD data frame I only can say that it's even slower.

How could I enhance the performance of my code? Could anybody perhaps additionally provide some basic rules (or related information sources) about this kind of performance enhancing?

(I'm working with R 3.x/64 and a Win 7/64 AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor, 4 GHz, 16 GB machine. The CPU stays rather cool when running, the RAM groans at it's limits.)

Here I give an example code with measured system times in comments:

```
# definitions
r <- 1e5 # number of rows
n <- 1e3 # number of dfs

# simulation of the list  
library(dplyr)
system.time(list <- lapply(1:n, function(i){       # 59.05 sec
  data.frame(a = rbinom(r, 1, .375)) %>%
    mutate(
      b = rnorm(r, 0, 2),
      c = .42 * rnorm(r, 0, 6),
      d = rbinom(r, 11, c(1:11)/11),
      e = rbinom(r, 1, .1),
      f = .02 * rnorm(r, 0, 5))
}))

# df w/ means & sds
system.time(list.s <- data.frame(                  # 73.20 sec
  list.mean = round(rowMeans(sapply(list, colMeans)), 2),
  list.sd = round(sapply(do.call(rbind, list), sd), 2)))
```

Comment: I don't know what you are simulating but you should spend some time considering the algorithm. Anyway, why do you call rnorm/binom inside a loop? Do one call in split the return vector afterwards.

Comment: The example is part of a survey simulation. Consider e. g. 'a' as a treatment variable, 'd' as number of children, 'e' membership, 'b', 'c', 'f' some random normal distributed effects. I excluded parameters and formulas here for sake of brevity. Could you eventually clarify your proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Rolands comment, you can create large population data beforehand and then simply subset it for each 'sample'/ iteration. Example:

```
## create large population data:

s <- 1e6 # probably big enough for this problem
set.seed(12)
d <- matrix(NA, nrow = s, ncol = 6) #..
# using matrix is more efficient than data.frame
d[,1] <- rbinom(s, 1, .375)
d[,2] <- rnorm(s, 0, 2)
d[,3] <- .42 * rnorm(s, 0, 6)
d[,4] <- rbinom(s, 11, c(1:11)/11)
d[,5] <- rbinom(s, 1, .1)
d[,6] <- .02 * rnorm(s, 0, 5)
head(d)
#      [,1]        [,2]      [,3] [,4] [,5]        [,6]
# [1,]    0  0.73853351  1.097805    1    0 -0.06233008
# [2,]    1 -0.05311206  4.447807    2    0 -0.01117972
# [3,]    1  1.71576276 -3.619708    6    0  0.02962562
# [4,]    0  1.92188205 -1.062585    2    0  0.03195146
# [5,]    0 -1.41097404  1.706067    2    0 -0.07751285
# [6,]    0  4.19130890  2.663374    8    0 -0.02316172


r <- 1e4 # number of rows
n <- 1e2 # number of dfs

si <- replicate(n, sample.int(s, r)) # get indexes for each sample 

# loop trougth samples and subset data:
nSamples <- lapply(1:n, function(x) {
  d[si[, x],]
  })

# and calculate colMeans:
list.mean2 = round(rowMeans(sapply(nSamples, colMeans)), 3)
list.mean2
# [1]  0.376  0.000 -0.003  5.999  0.100  0.000
```

compare with your results:

```
require(dplyr)
list1 <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
  data.frame(a = rbinom(r, 1, .375)) %>%
    mutate(
      b = rnorm(r, 0, 2),
      c = .42 * rnorm(r, 0, 6),
      d = rbinom(r, 11, c(1:11)/11),
      e = rbinom(r, 1, .1),
      f = .02 * rnorm(r, 0, 5))
})

list.mean1 = round(rowMeans(sapply(list1, colMeans)), 3)
list.mean1
# a      b      c      d      e      f 
# 0.375 -0.002  0.004  6.001  0.100  0.000
```

We can see that estimates of mean are quite similar with this small n value.

P.S. as 'list' is base R function you should not name variables with that name!

Lets wrap both approaches into functions to test timing:

```
mySim <- function(s, r, n) {
  d <- matrix(NA, nrow = s, ncol = 6)
  d[,1] <- rbinom(s, 1, .375)
  d[,2] <- rnorm(s, 0, 2)
  d[,3] <- .42 * rnorm(s, 0, 6)
  d[,4] <- rbinom(s, 11, c(1:11)/11)
  d[,5] <- rbinom(s, 1, .1)
  d[,6] <- .02 * rnorm(s, 0, 5)
  si <- lapply(1:n, function(x) sample.int(s, r))
  nSamples <- lapply(si, function(x) {
    d[x,]
  })
  list.mean2 = rowMeans(sapply(nSamples, colMeans))
  list.mean2
}

yourSim <- function(r, n) {
  require(dplyr)
  list1 <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
    data.frame(a = rbinom(r, 1, .375)) %>%
      mutate(
        b = rnorm(r, 0, 2),
        c = .42 * rnorm(r, 0, 6),
        d = rbinom(r, 11, c(1:11)/11),
        e = rbinom(r, 1, .1),
        f = .02 * rnorm(r, 0, 5))
  })
  list.mean1 = rowMeans(sapply(list1, colMeans))
  list.mean1
}

system.time(mySim(1e6, 1e4, 1e2)) # ~ 0.6 sek
system.time(yourSim(1e4, 1e2)) # ~ 1.5 sek

# if s = 1e7 :
system.time(mySim(1e7, 1e4, 1e2)) # ~ 4.53 sek
```

We can see that creating large population data for small n and r values is not increasing speed.

Lets take `s` as 1e6 ( 1 million), but you should yourself investigate if it
is sufficient.

If we compere timings for larger 'r' and 'n' values:

```
system.time(r1 <- mySim(1e6, 1e5, 1e3)) # ~ 20 sek
system.time(r2 <- yourSim(1e5, 1e3)) # ~ 60 sek

round(r1, 3)
# [1]  0.376 -0.003 -0.002  6.001  0.100  0.00
round(r2, 3)
# a     b     c     d     e     f 
# 0.375 0.000 0.000 6.000 0.100 0.000
```

About calculating SD:
maybe you want to use 'rowSds()' or 'colSds()' from package 'matrixStats'?

Also i would suggest that you investigate Rcpp package, which could be useful for speeding the code even more.

Comment: Indeed quite impressive speed difference. But why is it necessary in the dfs to draw a sample for each single row (rather than only one)? In my real roadworks (where I'm BTW bootstrapping 11 columns from an other sample) `si` is getting quite huge (thus slow again) and I'm facing the `Error in d[x, ] : subscript out of bounds` when I set `s <- 1e6,  r <- 1e5, n <- 1e4` for 30 columns as I need it.

Comment: we do not draw sample for each row, we draw sample for each `n` (sample). or is there something wrong with variables? about your error, can you give reproducible example?

Comment: I'm adressing the difference between `si <- replicate(n, sample.int(s, r))` in your example (on top) and `si = lapply(1:n, function(x) sample.int(s, r))` in `mySim()` function.

Comment: PS: just to clarify, the "bootstrapping" is done by adding `d[, 3:13] <- as.matrix(subset.vars[sample.int(nrow(subset.vars), n)])` (drawn from an external df) to the function. The error (above) occurs while `lapply(si, function(x) {...}`

Comment: generally it is the same, first creates matrix of indexes to take for each sample, but the other creates list. You could also do the sub-setting in one step by 'nSamples <- lapply(1:n, function(x) {d[sample.int(s, r),]})'

Comment: then the error probably is related with creation of d[, 3:13]

Comment: Negative (commented out line).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155819/discussion-between-minem-and-jaysf).

Comment: Since the final solution was clearly pointed out by you, I'm awarding you with the answer. Thank you for your help!